# SQLite3 - Printing the lowest costing book from a specific user's wishlist

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, join, select

I'm creating a database that keeps track of books, users, and what books each user has on their wishlist. What I'm trying to calculate in particular is looking up the wishlist for a particular user named Jess, and then printing out the lowest priced book(s) on that person's wishlist.

The query I made for this right now prints 'The Hunger Games' as the lowest priced item on Jess's wishlist, but the problem is Jess's wishlist does not contain a book called The Hunger Games. I thought my query might've been printing the lowest priced items for ALL books in the database and not books on Jess's wishlist, but I wasn't sure why it's only printing one book when there are several books matching the lowest price 10.00.

What the query SHOULD print is 'The Fault in Our Stars' priced at 10.00 as Jess's lowest priced book on his wishlist given that the other two remaining books in his wishlist are priced at 30.00.

I'm not sure what's wrong with the logic of my query and would appreciate some help. The key that both the books and wishlist tables have in common are the book ids, so I thought the tables could be joined that way.

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS books(
      id integer NOT NULL primary key UNIQUE, 
      title text NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
      genre text NOT NULL, 
      price integer NOT NULL, 
      units_available integer NOT NULL 
      );

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS wishlist(
      owners_username integer NOT NULL,
      book_id integer NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (owners_username, book_id),
      FOREIGN KEY (owners_username) REFERENCES users (username),
      FOREIGN KEY (book_id) REFERENCES books (id)
      );
```

Data in books:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO books VALUES(48067, 'The Maze Runner', 'Dystopian', 10.00, 20); 
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO books VALUES(5860, 'The Hunger Games', 'Dystopian', 10.00, 4); 
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO books VALUES(48070, 'The Sorcerer's Stone', 'Fantasy', 30.00, 10); 
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO books VALUES(50547, 'The Fault in Our Stars', 'Contemporary', 10.00, 235);
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO books VALUES(48400, 'Hamlet', 'Classic', 10.00, 62);
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO books VALUES(48399, 'Romeo and Juliet', 'Classic', 10.00, 102);
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO books VALUES(55620, 'Pride and Prejudice', 'Classic', 30.00, 5); 
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO books VALUES(55621, 'Oliver Twist', 'Classic', 10.00, 21);
```

Data for all wishlists stored in database:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO wishlist VALUES('Bob',  48400);
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO wishlist VALUES('Jess', 55620);
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO wishlist VALUES('Jess', 50547);
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO wishlist VALUES('Jess', 48070);
```

My query:

```
SELECT title, MIN(price) as lowest_price FROM books NATURAL JOIN wishlist where owners_username = 'Jess';

title             lowest_price
----------------  ------------
The Hunger Games  11
```

Comment: NATURAL JOIN... Don't be lazy, specify the join columns!

Comment: Can you also specify the expected result?

Comment: The expected result should be 'The Fault in Our Stars' priced at 10.00. This is due to Jess's other two wishlist books being priced at 30.00 each, so The Fault in Our Stars is automatically the lowest priced book in his wishlist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use join and specify the columns. You query works once you specify it.

```
 SELECT title, MIN(price) as lowest_price 
    FROM books JOIN wishlist on id = book_id 
    where owners_username = 'Jess';
```